# How To Include SDL2 in Source Files(.cpp)

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, sdl-2

I have been trying to figure out how to portable include SDL2 in my library. I have come to the solution that if I were to include SDL2 in the source files I wouldn't have to worry about the include path. The only extra thing I would have to do is forward declare types of SDL2. I successfully compiled the code, but when I tried to include my library errors of functions being undefined popped up, here is an example, **undefined reference to 'SDL_Init'** Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Here is an example:

App.h

```
#include <iostream>

struct SDL_Window;

class App{
   public:
     SDL_Window w;
     App(){}
     App(int width, int height)
};
```

App.cpp

```
#include "App.h"

#include <SDL.h>

App::App(int width, int height){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    w = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
}
```

CMakeLists.txt Main

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

set(PROJECT_NAME MyProject)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

Project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 1.0.0)

add_subdirectory(extern/SDL2)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

CMakeLists.txt Src

```
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

file(GLOB SDL2_HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/include/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SDL2_SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/src/*.c" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/src/*.cpp")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCES} ${SDL2_SOURCE} ${SDL2_HEADER_FILES}) 

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/src" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/include" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include") 

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC SDL2main PUBLIC SDL2-static)

set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin"
)
```

CMakeLists.txt Test

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

Project(Test)

include_directories(Test PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../MyProject/include")

add_executable(Test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Test "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../MyProject/lib/libMyProject.a")
```

Comment: So, do you want to build SDL2 by yourself (according to this line `file(GLOB_RECURSE SDL2_SOURCES ...)` or do you want to link with **existed** library (`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC SDL2main PUBLIC SDL2-static)`)? If the former, then you shouldn't link with the SDL2. If the latter, then you need to link your application with SDL2 too (the library `libMyProject.a` doesn't carry this linkage because it is **static** library).

Comment: I guess I want to build SDL2 by myself so I won’t need to worry about another library file

Comment: Note, that building SDL2 by yourself is unlikely "just enumerate source files and pass them to the compiler". SDL2 has support for building via CMake, so you may just include its source directory via `add_subdirectory` call and let SDL2's `CMakeLists.txt` to do the rest of building.

Comment: So I shouldn’t use SDL2main or SDL2-static in my building process?

Comment: If you build SDL2 as part of your library, then yes, linking with SDL2main and SDL2-static is not needed. If you build SDL2 with `add_subdirectory` approach, then you need to link with the resulted targets.

Comment: Ok thanks I will test this out later!

Comment: Still get the same error without the target_link_library do you have any other thoughts?